# Create docker image with specified CUDA toolkits and pytorch

Tags: docker

I'm using clusters of my corporation by ICM. It provides a convenient way to configure the remote by docker:

[image]

So, I want to build a docker image of my developing environment (**python packages**, **cuda**, some utility scripts like `screen` and `rsync`, also some necessary **data**) to deploy on the remote machine. Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.7.1-cuda11.0-cudnn8-runtime

WORKDIR /app

RUN sudo apt-get install rsync
RUN sudo apt-get install screen
RUN conda create --prefix /data/vxxx/nn python=3.8
RUN conda init

# shotcut for activating my environment
RUN echo 'alias nn="conda activate /data/xxx/nn"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN source ~/.bashrc
RUN nn

RUN pip3 install torchtext==0.8.1 pandas scipy scikit-learn transformers tensroboard -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

# copy files from windows
COPY /mnt/c/test .

RUN cd /data
RUN mkdir xxx
RUN cd xxx
RUN mkdir Data
RUN mkdir Code
RUN cd Code
RUN git clone https://github.com/namespace-Pt/Document-Reduction.git

RUN git config --global user.name 'xxx'
RUN git config --global user.email 'xxx@1.com'

CMD [ "sleep", "infinity"]
```

I'm new to docker and I followed the official python image tutorial, I have the following questions:

1. what is `WORKDIR`, does it mean to create a new directory where all files will be stored?
2. why my `COPY` command is not working?
3. how to publish my image to make it usable for the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Beginner here, from what i understood.

1. WORKDIR Is work directory for other commands as RUN, CMD, COPY or ADD.
2. Don't know. I will double check directories paths.
3. Don't know. Normally i'am using dockerhub

Comment: Thank you. I found some alternative solution to Docker.